# authorized_keys does not present for new user

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I want to setup an ssh key in a machine of Linux running under AWS in EC2 cloud.

For that firstly, I installed **cygwin**, then I followed the following steps  :

1. `ssh-keygen -t dsa -f ~/.ssh/<key name> -C "<username of remote server>@<ip>"`
2. `cat ~/.ssh/<key name>.pub | ssh  <username of remote server>@<ip> "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Now the 1st statement executes successfully but the 2nd statement shows

```
bash: /home/<username of server>/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file exists
```

Prior to this, I connected to the remote machine in root mode and created the user, that I am specifying at the command 1, 2 (username)

And I saw that the file  is not present in the remote server for the user I created explicitly, but it is present for the user **root**.

Comment: Are the `&lt;`s and `&gt;`s an encoding problem in your paste, or did you use them in your actual calls?

Comment: Its an encoding problem, I used the signs of  greater than and less than, further more if I would have used the &gt;in my command it will throw an command not found
:P

Comment: Ok, but you did put your _actual_ key name, user name and ip there, right?

Comment: Yeah.....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new linux instance, you specify a key pair that you want to use. You have a choice of creating a key pair, and downloading the public key, or uploading a private key.

In your steps, you never reference the key pair you specified when you created the instance.  So the 2nd command should be something like:

```
cat ~/.ssh/<key name>.pub | ssh -i ~/.ssh/<key specified when launching instance> ec2-user@<public id> ...
```

ec2-user may be different depending on what AMI you used to create your instance - ubuntu is the default user for ubuntu instances, for example.

Comment: Thanks I created the file explicitly and then followed the same steps it worked...
:)

Answer (score 2):

> bash: /home//.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file exists

When you create a new user, the `~/.ssh` directory is not created by default. You will have to create the `~/.ssh/` directory and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file yourself.

On your server, check whether `~/.ssh` or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` exists. Looking at the error you have, it seems that it does not.